# Absolute Value Inequality (another)

Tags: inequality

> Solve the following inequality
>
> $$|a-2| > |a+4|$$

Here I separated it into cases as shown

> $a<-4$

$$-(a-2) > -(a+4) \implies 2-a>-a-4 \implies 0>-6$$

Always true, so we get $\mathbb{R} \cap (-\infty  , -4) = (-\infty  ,-4)$

> $-4<a<2$

$$-(a-2)>a+4 \implies 2-a>a+4 \implies a<-1$$

Taking interception  $(-4,2)$ $\cap $ $(-\infty,-1)$

> $a>2$

$$a-2 > a+4 \implies -2>4 $$

Always false, so no solution from there. Finally, I checked end points and noticed that they do not work  in this inequality. However, I do not know how to proceed further. Could you assist me?

Regards

Comment: With $\;a=4\;$ your inequality is $$2=|4-2|>|4+4|=8...\text{you still think this is true?}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Not really, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

If you interpret the absolute values in terms of distance, it is immediate:

$|a-2|>|a+4|$ means $a$ is nearer to $-4$ than to $2$, so it is less than the arithmetic mean of $2$ and $-4$:
$$a<\frac{2-4}2=-1$$

*Other method*:
\begin{align}
|a-2|>|a+4|&\iff(a-2)^2>(a+4)^2 \\
&\iff a^2-4a+4>a^2+8a+16\\
&\iff 12a+12<0\iff a<-1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

As commented, $\;a=4\;$ doesn't really fits in the inequality. You can now put your solution set as

$$(-\infty,-4)\cup\left((-4,-2)\cap(-\infty,-1)\right)=(-\infty,-4)\cup(-4,-1)=(-\infty,-1)\setminus\{-4\}$$

Comment: What does this mathematical symbol mean \?

Comment: Set difference. Sometimes it is also used $\;A-B\;$ ... A simple minus sign.

Comment: The right answer seems to be $(-\infty, -1)$ according to my textbook. Do we get it from your final interval?:

Comment: That is correct, @Enzo . Your solution didn't even take into account $\;a=-4\;$ (perhaps you should have done this in the first case). That you have an inequality < or > doesn't mean you must take your cases in the same way

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish the following cases:
$$x\geq 2$$ then we get $$x-2>x+4$$
$$-4\le x<2$$ then we get $$x-2>-x+4$$
$$x<-4$$ then we have $$-x+2>-x-4$$

Answer (score 1):

$|(a+1)-3|>|(a+1)+3|;$

$x:=a+1$;

$|x-(+3)| >|x-(-3)|;$

Real number line :

Distance from a point $x$ to $(+3)$ is bigger than from $x$ 
to $(-3)$,  i.e. $x<0.$

(Note : At $x=0$ both distances are equal, for $x <0$, $x$ is to the left of $0$ , closer to $(-3)$ ).

$x= a+1<0$, $a<-1$.